# Rails Sidekiq Queue size not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a Rails app with 2 jobs (ImportCsvJob and ProcessCsvJob). So that I can visibly hint in the app that there are still jobs in the queue I have this helper method (inside application_helper.rb):

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def queued_job_count
        Sidekiq::Queue.new.size
    end
end
```

Then I use it on my index controller which is then passed to the view for processing and giving the visual hint in the app.

```
  def index
    @still_have_jobs = !queued_job_count.zero?
  end
```

However, this works when I still had 1 background Job (ImportCsvJob), but when I added the (ProcessCsvJob) it does not work anymore.

**import_csv_job.rb**

```
require 'open-uri'

class ImportCsvJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(csv_record)
    csv_record[:object_changes] = ApplicationController.helpers.generate_hash(csv_record[:object_changes])
    ObjectRecord.create(csv_record)
  end
end
```

**process_csv_job.rb**

```
class ProcessCsvJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(csv_path)
    csv_file = open(csv_path,'rb:UTF-8')

    options = {
        row_sep: :auto, col_sep: ",", 
        user_provided_headers: [:object_id, :object_type, :timestamp, :object_changes], 
        remove_empty_values: true, 
        headers_in_file: true
    }

    SmarterCSV.process(csv_file, options) do |array|
        ImportCsvJob.perform_later(array.first)
    end
  end

end
```

and lastly, in the model where this is called:

```
ProcessCsvJob.perform_later(gdrive.uploaded_file_link)
```

When I try to debug in Rails console using Sidekiq::Queue.new.size, it still gives out 0.

Running:

```
redis-server
bundle exec sidekiq
```

Comment: So for clarification, you are actually seeing a job execute in the default queue from sidekiq console / web interface, but running Sidekiq::Queue.new.size simultaneously is returning 0?

Comment: @Bryce yes, I uploaded a csv file for processing - in the sidekiq console it is being processed but still getting 0 from the Sidekiq::Queue.new.size.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what `Sidekiq::Queue.all` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically I added a monitoring for sidekiq using the web interface to see what was happening:

[image]

And as I inspected, there were no enqueued tasks nor scheduled since most of the job is set to perform almost immediately (on parallel).

Thus here's my solution to know if the count of busy jobs:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def queued_job_count
        Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new.first['busy']
    end
end
```

and then on the index:

```
  def index
    @still_have_jobs = !queued_job_count.zero?
  end
```

it works! :)

Answer (score 5):

A job that is executing is not enqueued anymore.  The Sidekiq process has already popped it off the queue and is executing it.  The queue is empty but the job is not finished yet.